# Google Voice Chrome extension shows new message, but Google Voice shows "you're all caught up"

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, google-voice

Whenever I run the Google Voice chrome extension it shows 1 unanswered message. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension but it still shows an unanswered message with a numerical one "1" in the bottom corner. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with the new Google Voice, check this link below to find the legacy interface

Make sure this says ["All Caught Up"](https://voice.google.com/messages#unread)

Click the menu button in the top right.

[image: menu]

Click on the "Legacy Google Voice"

[image: Legacy Google Voice]

Go to this URL,

- https://www.google.com/voice/b/0#unread

Click on all the messages.